# R-Tree query with adapted std::pair point type

Tags: c++, boost, boost-geometry

I am hitting a compile-time assertion with the following (Rcpp) code. This code inserts 10^6 random points into a vector, builds and r-tree from that vector and then queries for points falling with a box bounded by (1/3, 1/3) and (2/3, 2/3).

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(BH)]]
// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]]

#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/register/box.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/register/point.hpp>

namespace bg = boost::geometry;
namespace bgi = boost::geometry::index;

using key_type = std::pair<double, double>;
using box_type = std::pair<key_type, key_type>;
using range_type = std::vector<key_type>;

BOOST_GEOMETRY_REGISTER_POINT_2D(key_type, double,
                                 bg::cs::cartesian,
                                 first, second);

BOOST_GEOMETRY_REGISTER_BOX(box_type, key_type, first, second);

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void test_it()
{
  range_type data;

  for (int i = 0; i != 1e6; ++i)
    data.emplace_back(R::runif(0, 1), R::runif(0, 1));

  using rtree_type = bgi::rtree<key_type, bgi::linear<16>>;

  rtree_type rt(data);

  key_type p1 = std::make_pair(0.33, 0.33),
    p2 = std::make_pair(0.66, 0.66);

  box_type roi = std::make_pair(p1, p2);

  range_type res;

  rt.query(bgi::contains(roi), std::back_inserter(res));

}
```

Compiles fine without the last query line. Compiler output is:

```
In file included from geom_test.cpp:7:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/geometry.hpp:17:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/geometry/geometry.hpp:50:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/geometry/strategies/strategies.hpp:33:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/geometry/strategies/disjoint.hpp:24:
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/geometry/strategies/relate.hpp:23:
/usr/local/include/boost/geometry/strategies/within.hpp:80:5: error: no matching function for call to 'assertion_failed'
    BOOST_MPL_ASSERT_MSG
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/boost/mpl/assert.hpp:435:48: note: expanded from macro 'BOOST_MPL_ASSERT_MSG'
#define BOOST_MPL_ASSERT_MSG( c, msg, types_ ) \
                                               ^
/usr/local/include/boost/mpl/assert.hpp:429:9: note: expanded from macro '\
BOOST_MPL_ASSERT_MSG_IMPL'
        boost::mpl::assertion_failed<(c)>( BOOST_PP_CAT(mpl_assert_arg,counter)::assert_arg() ) \
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/boost/mpl/assert.hpp:60:58: note: expanded from macro '\
BOOST_MPL_AUX_ASSERT_CONSTANT'
#   define BOOST_MPL_AUX_ASSERT_CONSTANT(T, expr) enum { expr }
                                                         ^~~~
```

Comment: FYI I used the "pedantic" details to make a self-contained example (see the answer) which lead me to the ASSERT in the code that explained that "contains" isn't implement for `Point` vs `Box` concepts.

Comment: @sehe What my code is not immediately understandable on its own? :)

Comment: Oh. I assumed the code was part of the "pedantic details". But, yeah, as you can see my answer corrected the code knowing what you really wanted to achieve. Your code wasn't clear even to the compiler, and it was much easier to validate what you _actually_ wanted to do with the description you typed. So, yeah, still helpful!

Comment: Hope you noticed the :) Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say

> then queries for points falling with a box bounded by (1/3, 1/3) and (2/3, 2/3)

Yet your code is looking for points that "contain" a box.

You probably meant:

```
rt.query(bgi::within(roi), std::back_inserter(res));
```

### Demo

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/53d0aa06bef1ecfd)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/register/box.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/register/point.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

namespace bg = boost::geometry;
namespace bgi = boost::geometry::index;

using key_type = std::pair<double, double>;
using box_type = std::pair<key_type, key_type>;
using range_type = std::vector<key_type>;

BOOST_GEOMETRY_REGISTER_POINT_2D(key_type, double, bg::cs::cartesian, first, second)
BOOST_GEOMETRY_REGISTER_BOX(box_type, key_type, first, second)

int main() {
    std::mt19937 engine { std::random_device{}() };
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> dist(0,1.0);

    range_type data;

    for (int i = 0; i != 1e6; ++i)
        data.emplace_back(dist(engine), dist(engine));

    using rtree_type = bgi::rtree<key_type, bgi::linear<16> >;

    rtree_type rt(data);

    box_type const roi {{0.33, 0.33}, {0.66,0.66}};

    range_type res;
    rt.query(bgi::within(roi), std::back_inserter(res));

    std::cout << res.size() << " results\n";
}
```

Prints something like

```
109073 results
```